# How to use terniary operator in python with objects

Tags: python, django, operators

I want to access the object property like this

```
'region'     :obj.region ? obj.region.name : "None"
```

The thing is in my class i want that if obj.region does not exist then i want none in the region. But if it has region associated then i want the name of the region.

The region is not true false but object

How can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments:

```
'region': obj.region.name if obj.region else "None"
```

But I wouldn't be surprised if it should be:

```
'region': obj["region"]["name"] if "region" in obj and obj["region"] else "None"
```

Depending on exactly what `obj` is - whether it's an actual object or a dictionary.

Comment: @user1776347 As long as whatever condition you use for the `if` part can be evaluated as `true` or `false`, then it should work fine. I'm not exactly sure of the structure of possibility of values in your `obj` variable, but I think this is what you're looking for.